# Rishonim who wrote on Kodshim

Tags: history, korban, commentaries, rishonim

Seder Kodshim is composed of largely currently non-applicable laws, relating to sacrifices and the running of the Temple.

The Rambam wrote on Kodshim.  So did Rashi and the Ba'alei Tosefos.  To the best of my knowledge, we do not have Ramban, Rashba, Ritva, or Ran on Kodshim.

What other Rishonim wrote novelae or codified *halacha* of Kodshim?

(Motivation: I am wondering how many Rishonim I can bring as examples of having spent time on something which was not, in their lifetime, practically applicable.)

Comment: Check out _Keneset Rishonim_. Even if they didn't publish with that title they spent time learning about it.

Comment: How about we compile a list in a community wiki answer?

Comment: @Fred started.  Feel free to add.

Answer (score 4):

Including those listen in the question, those who wrote on Kodshim include:

- Rashi (11th century)
- Maimonides (12th century
- Tosefos:

  - Rabbeinu Yaakov (ר"י)
  - Rabbeinu Yitzchok Ben Asher HaLevi (ריב"א)
- Rabbeinu Gershom comments on seven tractates: *Bechoros*, *Kerisus*, *Me'ila*, *Temura*, *Chullin*, *Menachos*, and *Arachin*.
- The *Shita Mekubetzes* writes on all tractates including the recently published *Chullin*
- The Aguda

Otherwise:

- On *Chullin*: Rif (along with Ba'al Hama'or, Ran, *Nimukei Yosef*, Ramban, the *Milchamos*, Rabbeinu Yehonasan), Rabbeinu Chanan'el, Rashba, Ritva, Ran, Tosafos HaRosh, Riv'van, Meiri, Rosh, Hagahos Ashri, Mordechai, Or Zarua', Piskei Rid, R' Yehuda HaKohein, R' Menachem Mendel Kloizner, (also, a few remarks by the Ra'avad on the Rif here, as well as on *Zevachim* and *Menachos*)
- On *Menachos* (התכלת): Rif, Rabbeinu Yehonasan, *Nimukei Yosef*, Rosh, Hagahos Ashri, Mordechai, Or Zarua'
- On *Menachos*: Piskei Rid
- On *Bechoros*: Rosh, Piskei Rid, Ramban, Maharit Algazi,
- On *Zevachim*: Piskei Rid, and "Echad MiGedolei HaRishonim"
- On *Me'ila*: "Shenei Peirushim Kadmonim"
- On *Arachin*: "Echad MiGedolei HaRishonim"
- On *Temura*: "Echad MiGedolei HaRishonim"

Comment: @Fred are those on the _Kodshim_-related sections of those masechtas (as opposed to the "yoreh de'ah" sections)?

Comment: It varies, I think.

Comment: @Fred I assume the Chulin list is primarily Y.D.-ish.

Comment: Yeah. So the ones on חולין and התכלת were commenting to a large degree on material that was directly relevant to contemporary halacha.

Comment: I don't think Chulin should be on this list.