# List of which Rishonim wrote on each Masechta?

Tags: history, product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, commentaries, rishonim

I would like to know if anyone has made a comprehensive list/chart of which Rishonim wrote on each masechta in shas. 
Such a list would include details such as: Masechtos where Rashi is not rashi, the ran isn't the Ran, etc; Rishonim we know wrote on a particular maseches but has been lost to history; which version of tosfos (tuch, shantz) is printed on the daf...
I presume a spreadsheet would be the most legible way to organize such a list.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15520/which-masechtot-dont-really-have-rashi and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55188/rishonim-who-wrote-on-kodshim have data that would be included on such a list

Comment: This might help: http://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=160520

Answer (score 7):

R. [Menachem M. Kasher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Kasher) compiled such a bibliographic list in his Sare HaElef (Section 4), some of which is available [here](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A3) for free (though not the section you’re looking for).